# Removing code inside a code html tag

Tags: r, regex

I have text which contains code.

It is possible to recognize because code exist into an html tag like this

```
<code> print(i)
</code>
```

I know it is possible to remove html tags in R?

However how is it possible to remove the content into a specific tag like my case?

The code I mention exists in text. 
A better example:

`You can find an incredible solution if you use <code> print(i) </code> and you will solve your problem.`

and I want to remove the specific tag and what it is inside the tag and have only:

```
 You can find an incredible solution if you use and you will solve your problem
```

Comment: Something like this?: `gsub("<code>.+?</code>", "", text)`

Comment: Obligatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/474349

Comment: @HongOoi, people need to stop linking that answer when the questions are not about parsing a whole webpage with regex (which is probably possible anyway due to the fact that most regex engines aren't as regular as the name suggests) - it'd just be more efficient to use a document parser for it.

Comment: @KyleFairns No. We need to keep linking that answer. Otherwise people will think, oh, that was easy, and go from "how do I remove a <code> tag" to "how do I remove table tags" to "how do I handle css descriptors" and before you know it, Zalgo has come.

Comment: @HongOoi, when the ones that can't easily be done with regex come up, thats when the answer should be linked.

Comment: @KyleFairns think of it as pre-empting those kinds of questions

Comment: @HongOoi But it is irrelevant to the questions that you are linking it on, therefore, you shouldn't link it.

Comment: @KyleFairns think of it as an educational opportunity.